# SwiftUI: How to reduce spacing between .navigationTitle and Section in a InsetGroupedListStyle

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

I have a list that I navigate to from a navigationLink. How do I reduce the space between the title and the start of the list? Applying a padding causes visual artifacts when entering the view.
[image: Example Top Spacing]

Comment: Will need to see your actual code. Can't guess what you have done that resulted this look.

Answer (score 0):

I added a       .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 8)) to the section. This causes the padding inside the list to disappear too, but you can add .padding to it manually to get a satisfactory result. The trailing 8 inset is because else it will never neatly align the added chevron by the navigation link.